# need help in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need my URL to be like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php?title=about -> http://example.com/about/
```

The title more than 50, and same goes to pages.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Whilst mosg's link does have the answers you're looking for, I figured it might be easier to just explain the part you need.

I'm not sure if you want to redirect index.php?title=about TO /about/, or if you want /about/ to silently call index.php?title=about.

For `/about/` -> `/index.php?title=about` (silently):

```
RewriteEngine on  # turn on re-writing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php.*  # for every non-rewritten request
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?title=$1 [L] # rewrite to index.php
```

For `/index.php?title=about` -> `/about/` (not silently)

```
RewriteEngine on  # turn on re-writing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php?title=.*  # for index.php?title=slug request
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] # rewrite to /slug/
```

Hope this helps :)